# Maven error: -fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (package-javadocs) on project globalmentor-core: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\globalmentor-core\target\apidocs' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (package-javadocs) on project globalmentor-core: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR

Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\globalmentor-core\target\apidocs' dir.

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR

Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\globalmentor-core\target\apidocs' dir.

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.failOnError(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:6018)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocJar.execute(JavadocJar.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException:
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - fuzzyMatcher TYPEVAR

Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\magno\Documents\Globalmentor\globalmentor-core\target\apidocs' dir.

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeJavadocCommandLine(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:5163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2075)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocJar.execute(JavadocJar.java:188)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Alguém pode ajudar a resolver este erro? Houve problemas no Javadoc e por um tempo foi usado essas linhas adicionais no POM para resolver esse problema:

```
<!-- turn off Javadoc errors from warnings; requires JDK 8 -->
<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
```

O problema é que agora foi necessário a correção de todos os Javadocs para deixar a biblioteca pronta para fazer upload para o maven, todos os javadocs foram consertados, mas este problema persiste. Alguma solução? Não encontro esse tipo de erro em lugar algum.

Aqui está o arquivo pom.xml para tentar ajudar com maior informações sobre o que poderia ser o problema.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.globalmentor</groupId>
<artifactId>globalmentor-core</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>GlobalMentor Core</name>
<url>http://www.globalmentor.com/</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/javascript</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <bottom><![CDATA[<em>Copyright © 1996-2012 GlobalMentor, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</em>]]></bottom>
                        <quiet>true</quiet>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>package-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:all</additionalparam>
                                <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

E aqui estão as informações sobre as versões do Maven a Java que estou utilizando atualmente:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T14:41:47-02:00)
Java version: 1.8.0_92, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: Já tentou instalar uma nova versão do java e apontar para lá?

Comment: Mas o JDK já está na versão mais recente. :(

Comment: O erro está vindo [deste código](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/tools/javac/api/JavacTrees.java#615), portanto você parece ter algum erro na sua declaração do javadoc dos type parameters de um método. Verifique se há algum warning no quando você compila o código...